# How can I show that the duplicate question answers my question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

*Very* often on SO (and other 'exchanges),  an question of mine is marked as a duplicate.

How can I mark that the question I duplicated answers my question? Leaving a comment seems like the best way to do this, but comments aren't forever.

Comment: Question is, why you want to do it? What's the goal?

Comment: @shadowwizard to show future users who have your exact problem, that this (subtly different) answer marked as the 'original' does have an answer.

Comment: So comment on your own question seems the best option.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 'comments aren't forever'

Comment: That's the best we can do, and usually just having it marked as dupe is enough. :)

Answer (score 6):

In that case you don't need to; it's implied by it staying as a duplicate.

If you don't feel it is a duplicate then you would edit your question clarifying why.

Comment: It seems counter intuitive (to me)  that 'not doing something' is by default approval.

Comment: Admitadly I know how duplicates work, however even as someone new I think seeing a question with the duplicate notice, linking to the other question with answers would be enough for me to follow the link, read the answer(s) and solve my problem. I understand your point though, from the askers point of view it might be nice to be able to confirm that you did get the help you needed. If you really want to do something you could upvote the question and answer that helped.